# Install 32-bit version of java8 on ubuntu 18 64-bit by apt command

Tags: apt, software-installation, 18.04, java, 32-bit

I found this solution for similar question:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

I can't comment on the original post. My question is, does this procedure install the 64 or the 32-bit version of Java?
If, as I suppose, it installs the 64bit version, is there a way to install the 32-bit version?

-------update-----

I tried to look by apt for a bundle 386 (on my ubuntu 18 64-bit) but I did not find it.

I also tried to install manually but it does not work.

I downloaded 32bit version and untar in `/opt/java` and if I enter the `/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_181/bin` directory and try to execute the `java -version` command I get the error `-bash: /usr/bin/ java: No such file or directory`.

in `/usr/bin` i have:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root   22 Sep 27 15:51  java -> /etc/alternatives/java*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root   23 Sep 27 15:51  javac -> /etc/alternatives/javac*
```

and in `/etc/alternative/`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Sep 27 15:51 java -> /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_181/bin/java*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Sep 27 15:51 javac -> /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_181/bin/javac*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `apt show oracle-java8-installer`. Also if you want to specify the architecture append it like:

```
apt install postgresql-10:i386
```

I would suggest to download and install java binary  from: [Java Downloads for Linux](https://www.java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp).

Comment: It's generally not recommended to install binaries unless that's the last resort. With APT packages (and snaps), updating to a new version is very easy. Uninstalling is also fairly easy. With binaries, both are usually more difficult.